# Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, confusion-matrix, mlxtend

here is the snippet of my code :

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_pred = (model.predict(X_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")

mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=mat, class_names=label.classes_, show_normed=True, figsize=(7,7))
```

I am getting this error on the 4th line **"Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets"**  so the confusion matrix is not shown , so anyone could tell me what's wrong on it ? Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: What's in `y_test`?

Comment: What kind of model is `model`?  What does `model.predict(X_test)` look like (and subsequently what does `y_pred` look like), and, as tobiv already asks, what does `y_test` look like?  // Always try to provide a minimal reproducible example; here, a small dataset that gives the same issue and the code that produced the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add one more step to your calculations.
Right now you're doing this:

`y_pred = (model.predict(X_test) > 0.5).astype("int32")`
But usually, for binary classification, `model.predict(X_test)` produces two values - for class 0 and class 1. You need to take the values for class 1:

`y_pred = (model.predict(X_test)[:, 1] > 0.5).astype("int32")`

After this the confusion matrix should work without errors.